# How to fix the below python 3.6 error function' object has no attribute data?

Tags: python, dataset

While i am running the below code i have seeing the error "'function' object has no attribute 'data'". Please help me how to fix it. I have python 3.6.

```
   import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits

digits = load_digits

from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
folds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3)

scores_logistic = []
scores_svm = []
scores_rf = []

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(digits.data):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = digits.data[train_index], digits.data[test_index], \
                                       digits.target[train_index], digits.target[test_index]
    scores_logistic.append(get_score(LogisticRegression(), X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test))  
    scores_svm.append(get_score(SVC(), X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test))
    scores_rf.append(get_score(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=40), X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test))
```

Comment: I expect you meant to actually call the load_digits function in the third line: `digits = load_digits()`.

Comment: It's a typo. You bound the function to a name but didn't actually call the function using `()` as has been said.

Comment: i use it function as () by this. But next i found this error
 8 for train_index, test_index in kf.split(digits.data):
      9     X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = digits.data[train_index], digits.data[test_index], \
     10                                        digits.target[train_index], digits.target[test_index]




NameError: name 'kf' is not defined

Comment: I am facing the error. How to fix it please guide me.


c:\users\shani\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py:196: FutureWarning: The default value of gamma will change from 'auto' to 'scale' in version 0.22 to account better for unscaled features. Set gamma explicitly to 'auto' or 'scale' to avoid this warning.
  "avoid this warning.", FutureWarning)